# Using 7za x -aou to extract multiple files and keeping duplicates results in duplicate files having creation dates 1 hour apart, why?

Tags: 7zip

I currently have about 102 zip files, of which I would like to combine them into one folder. A lot of the files within the zip files between zip files have the same name and content. I do not want them to overwrite. I used the following command:

```
7za x '*.zip' -aou -o/Path/To/Export/To
```

This works fine in that, say if `zipfile1.zip` and `zipfile2.zip` had the same file called `IMG.jpg`, with the EXACT contant, it would create two names, one with `IMG.jpg` and the other with `IMG_1.jpg`.

HOWEVER, I noticed that upon comparing the files, the creation/modification time was off by 1 hour. Is there a reasonable explanation for why?

Comment: I dont have your answer but i suggest you to run different tests under different conditions. It might help. I tried but my creation and modification time are the same. Let me know your case.

Comment: Just guessing, but when I've seen offset issues like this elsewhere, it's usually a DST bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/5c86e830/?limit=250), it is not supported to preserve creation time due to lack of interest in the 7-zip team. It's not a great answer, but it seems to be the answer.